# Objective-C and Swift, using assistant editor. Nullability

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am currently following *Paul Hudson's* book *Objective-C for Swift developers*.

In a book, in chapter *Nullability*, I create a class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface PersonNullabilityCheck : NSObject @property NSString *name;
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
- (NSString*)fetchGreetingsForTime:(NSString*)time; @end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

After that, *Editor -> Assistant*. Finally, *Counterparts -> PersonNullabilityCheck.h (Swift 5 interface)*

At this point in the book, Paul shows how Swift sees this Objective-C class. And in the book it looks like this:

```
import Foundation

public class Person: NSObject {
    public var name: String!

    public init!(name:String!)
    public func fetchGreetingForTime(time: String!) -> String!
}
```

Everything here is implicitly unwrapped.

However, when I do the same, I can see this:

```
import Foundation

open class PersonNullabilityCheck : NSObject {

    open var name: String

    public init(name: String)

    open func fetchGreetings(forTime time: String) -> String
}
```

I assume, since the book was written, some new, better techniques were developed to handle nullability?

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me where the difference is, and how to read it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it, the answer was right there and I haven't noticed it.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

These lines of code that differ from the version from the book, make every element automatically non-nullable. Therefore I assume I don't have to worry to make a manual check, but if I want to make something non-nullable, I need to add it manually.

Thanks.